# How can I print a Value without NULL (behind) that Value in r?

Tags: r, na

I have a small problem. If I run my Code I get the number and NULL. I know that it is null but i just want to have the number.
My Code calculate the amount of NA Value. And it is **0**

```
pclassNaValue <- sum(is.na(titanic$Pclass))
print(cat("NA Value: ",pclassNaVal))
```

**Output that I get ->** NA Value:  0NULL

**Output that I want ->** NA Value:  0

I hope you guys can help me. I check a bit Stackoverflow and have not found similar question. It is possible that I not search correct because I cant give that problem a propper name.

Thank You

Best Regards 
Michael

Comment: You have `pclassNaValue <- sum(...)` and then try to print `pclassNaVal`.

Comment: @PoGibas I answered the question for me self. So I dont reply to the OP sry didnt know it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sry this is pclassNaVal. I misstype

Answer (score 3):

Scientist_Jake, in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48227715/8245406), says that he is

> Not sure what makes the NULL

It is the return value of `cat`. From the help page `help("cat")`, the `Value` section is

> Value
>
> None (invisible NULL).

So `print`is doing what it should, `invisible(NULL)` becomes visible. See the following example.

```
pclassNaVal <- 1    # assign any value, just for the code to run

result <- cat("NA Value: ", pclassNaVal)    # this writes 1 to stdout, without a newline
print(result)                               # and this prints NULL
#NULL
print(invisible(NULL))                      # so does this
#NULL
```

The suggestion by Scientist_Jake to use `paste0` solves the problem, the other suggestion in the edit also does so but doesn't print a newline, which can be bothering. You can `cat` any number of vectors, separated by commas, like this:

```
cat("NA Value: ", pclassNaVal, "\n")
```

Finally, sometimes `cat` is prettier than `print`. This is because `print` starts its output with a `[1]` (or whatever number if it spans multiple lines) and `cat`does not.

```
print(1)
[1] 1
cat(1, "\n")
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what makes the NULL, but paste0 can give you the output you want:
`print(paste0("NA Value: ",pclassNaValue))`

EDIT: Just remove the print function. `cat` concatenates and prints:
`cat("NA Value: ",pclassNaValue)`

Comment: Maybe you could add a final newline `"\n"` to the `cat` instruction.